# Get remaining of string (right) after x number of specific character - Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the remaining string (from right) after x number of a specific character... ex:

```
D-ERT-ESTTE
D-EST-AER-EJEL
D-E-AD
```

I would like to get all string data after the second '-'

Results Expected:

```
ESTTE
AER-EJEL
AD
```

I have tried modifying `substring(SKU,1,regexp_instr(SKU,'-',1,2)-1)`

, however this is only giving me giving me everything to the left of the second '-'... I need from the right though

Update: Looks like maybe the below works:

```
substr(SKU,regexp_instr(SKU,'-',1,2)+1)
```

Comment: it looks like maybe the below works?

substr(SKU,regexp_instr(SKU,'-',1,2)+1)

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
select fld1, SPLIT_PART(fld1,'-',3), substr(fld1,regexp_instr(fld1,'-',1,2)+1), regexp_instr(fld1,'-',1,2) from (
select 'D-ERT-ESTTE' fld1 from dual union all
select 'D-EST-AER-EJEL' from dual union all
select' D-E-ADF' from dual );
```

Answer (score 3):

I like @hkandpal solution that looks first for the index of the second character, and then gets the substring out.

Presenting this as a regex-only alternative - that extracts the first group that matches after the two characters are seen. The regex is `[^-]*-[^-]*-(.*)`:

```sql
select fld1, regexp_substr(fld1, '[^-]*-[^-]*-(.*)', 1, 1, 'c', 1) 
from (
    select 'D-ERT-ESTTE' fld1 union all
    select 'D-EST-AER-EJEL' union all
    select' D-E-ADF'
);
```

[image]